# Windows Memory Dump as a driver

Tags: windows, memory, driver

I am developing a Windows driver, which will likely run on mostly Windows 7 machines, and possibly Windows 10 in the future.

Is it possible to create a full memory dump within the context of the driver (kernel mode)? Will the method used be the same for both Windows 7 and 10?